# How can I use ES2016/ES7 proposal for async/await in my gulpfile.babel.js

Tags: javascript, gulp, babeljs

I have a very simple gulpfile.babel.js .

```
import 'babel-polyfill'

let y = ()=>{return Promise.resolve(true)}

async function awaitY() {
  let m = await y()
  console.log(m)
}

awaitY()
```

and the following dev dependencies in my package.json

```
"babel-core": "^6.7.4",
"babel-polyfill": "^6.7.4",
"babel-preset-es2015": "^6.6.0",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.5.0"
```

and the following in my .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015","stage-0"]
}
```

When I run gulp, i get the following error...

```
MacBook-Pro-2:gulptest jschlesser$ gulp
[15:26:17] Requiring external module babel-core/register
/Users/jschlesser/Dropbox (Personal)/prj/cursive/spout/gulptest/gulpfile.babel.js:4
  var ref = _asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {
                              ^

ReferenceError: regeneratorRuntime is not defined
    at /Users/jschlesser/Dropbox (Personal)/prj/cursive/spout/gulptest/gulpfile.babel.js:4:31
    at Object.<anonymous> (gulpfile.babel.js:5:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:435:26)
    at loader (/Users/jschlesser/Dropbox (Personal)/prj/cursive/spout/gulptest/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:126:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/jschlesser/Dropbox (Personal)/prj/cursive/spout/gulptest/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:136:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:311:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:366:17)
    at require (module.js:385:17)
    at Liftoff.handleArguments (/Users/jschlesser/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js:116:3)
MacBook-Pro-2:gulptest jschlesser$
```

I would like to know what steps are needed to use async/await in a gulpfile.    The error implies that gulp used a require hook to run the gulpfile through babel and it transformed the async function into a generator.

It says the error is on line 4.
`var ref = _asyncToGenerator(regeneratorRuntime.mark(function _callee() {`  .

But it looks like its not injecting all of the right stuff into that compiled file to use the regeneratorRuntime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a **separate entry point that loads the polyfill**, and *then* the main application file.

**gulpfile.babel-entry.js**

```
import 'babel-polyfill'
import './gulpfile.babel.js'
```

**gulpfile.babel.js**

```
let y = ()=>{return Promise.resolve(true)}

async function awaitY() {
  let m = await y()
  console.log(m)
}

awaitY()
```

[more info](https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7128)

Comment: This works.  I moved all of the contents of my gulpfile.babel.js to into a main.gulpfile.babel.js and added a statement `import './main.gulpfile.babel.js'`   However, i also was able to change my .babelrc file to not use the stage-0 preset and instead use a plugins entry `"plugins": ["transform-regenerator","syntax-async-functions"]` but omitting stage-0 in the presets.   This also works while not requiring that you put the 'main' portion of your gulpfile in a different module/file.  I tried having both the stage-0 preset and the plugin entries and it didn't work without the second module.

Comment: Thank you,  laggingreflex for the quick reply.   I think your solution is better than taking out the stage-0 preset because while there is 1 level of indirection of imports, it is in general a greater gain than removing it the stage-0 present and having to include individual plugins.  It will be less hassle long term if I want to use more features included in stage-0.  Your solution has my vote.  Wish i had more rep so i could up vote.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do is by supplying `babel-polyfill` as `gulp` parameter.

`$ gulp --require babel-polyfill`